# Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I am writing a small sample app with Xamarin and MvvmCross 6.4.2. I completed the Xamarin.Android version and am now starting the Xamarin.iOS version. I created a view controller for the first screen:

```
public class SignInViewController : MvxViewController<SignInViewModel>
{
    public SignInViewController() : base(nameof(SignInViewController), null)
    {
        
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        // never gets called...

        base.ViewDidLoad();
    }
}
```

When I run the app, I just get a blank screen and `ViewDidLoad` never gets called. In the application output it says:

> Failed to instantiate the default view controller for
> UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is
> not set?

My `Main.storyboard` is blank and I tried to modify it in Xcode Interface Builder to set my `SignInViewController` as the entry point, but I couldn't figure out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Failed to instantiate the default view controller for
> UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is
> not set?

This error happens due to a simple mistake in your storyboard. When your app starts, iOS needs to know precisely which view controller needs to be shown first – known as your default view controller.

To fix it, add a `ViewController` to your `Main.Storyboard` and set it as `Inital View Controller`.

[image]

Refer: [how-to-fix-the-error-failed-to-instantiate-the-default-view-controller-for-uimainstoryboardfile](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-fix-the-error-failed-to-instantiate-the-default-view-controller-for-uimainstoryboardfile)

And there are two `SignInViewController` in your project.

Use this one:

```
public partial class SignInViewController : UIViewController
{
    public SignInViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        // never gets called...

        base.ViewDidLoad();

        View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
    }
}
```

Update:

[image]

Comment: I am using Visual Studio for Mac, which does not support editing storyboard files, it needs to be done in Xcode Interface Builder. Also, I need `SignInViewController` to inherit from `MvxViewController<SignInViewModel>` so it works with MvvmCross.

Comment: I think I need to add a "root navigation view controller" so that it can navigate to my `SignInViewController`.

Comment: It's the same if you add a NaviagtionController in XCode.

Comment: I added a NaviagtionController in Xcode to `Main.storyboard` and a view controller with a red background so I know when I see it. I see the red background when I run the app, but my `ViewDidLoad` method in `SignInViewController` never gets called. I don't see anywhere to link the class like in your image in Xcode.